# checks an array at a particular index only

Tags: arrays, search

I  want to check an array to see that a value exists in a particular index. I believe in_array will not work as it searches the entire array for a value. I don't want to look the entire array but search at only one index.

My scenario is , I have two arrays-arr1 and arr2.I will be looping arr1.While looping I need to check whether value in arr1[id'] exists in arr2['transId']

Array to be searched (in my example arr2) is in the format (Array[0]=>Array([transId]=>3 [name]=>ABC) [1]=>Array([transId]=>4 [name]=>DEF))

Thanks

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you're trying to do this in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have to loop through all of `$arr2`.

```
$found = FALSE;
foreach ($arr2 as $arr2_arr) {
  if ($arr2_arr['transid'] == $arr1['id']) {
    $found = TRUE;
    break;
  }
}
```